# How to get the Flow or directional raster map using GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, direction

Aside from using `r.fill.dir` in GRASS, is this the script to produce the Flow or directional raster map? Is the output for the script the following graphic? http://grass.fbk.eu/grass63/screenshots/images/drastarrow.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first create the aspect raster with [r.slope.aspect](http://grass.polytechnic.edu.na/grass70/manuals/html70_user/r.slope.aspect.html) then display the arrows with [d.rast.arrow](http://grass.polytechnic.edu.na/grass70/manuals/html70_user/d.rast.arrow.html).

Comment: I used `r.slope.aspect elevation=rastermap`. It produced the error:                                         
`ERROR: You must specify at least one of the parameters: <slope>, <aspect>, <pcurv>, <tcurv>, <dx>, <dy>, <dxx>, <dyy> or <dxy>`. Which parameter to use for the r.slope.aspect is best to use in order to obtain a Flow or directional raster map ?

Comment: Use `r.slope.aspect elevation=inmap aspect=outmap min_slp_allowed=0.04` and adjust `min_slp_allowed` and the region resolution to get good results.

Comment: I used: `r.slope.aspect elevation=bul2 aspect=outmap1 min_slp_allowed=0.04`. It produced a gray map with slope-like structures. and I used: `d.rast.arrow map=outmap1`. It produced a raster map with a solid color. It did not contain arrows. I think the problem with the map is that its resolution is high that is why it did not produce arrows. How do I resolve it? Are my scripts correct? I need the arrows in order to know the direction of the elevation areas for a flood modelling algorithm that I will use. Thanks!

Comment: I'm having a trouble with the `d.arrow` script. Is there a problem with it? I read from http://www.mail-archive.com/grass-dev@lists.osgeo.org/msg12470.html that there is a problem with the `d.arrow`. Does anybody know how to resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: I've just tried it here, strange results, very small arrows.

Comment: Is there a way to make the arrows larger? Are the arrows generated per cell? I am thinking of making computation for the arrows cover more than one cell to lessen the number of arrows (averaging the elevation for every set of adjacent cells). Is there a GRASS script that would handle it?

Comment: The Z value of the ASPECT map is the flow heading. You can try something with that.

Comment: I tried `r.slope.aspect elevation=bul2 aspect=outmap1 min_slp_allowed=0.04 zfactor = 10.0` but the map that it produced is still solid green with no arrows in it..