# Arrow flow lines from a contour map

Tags: qgis, labeling, contour, direction, flow

using QGIS (or even GRASS) is it possible to label a contour lines shape with arrows that indicate the flow direction?

Briefly: I have a point shape with elevation values. I make an interpolation map and then I extract the contour lines.

Now how can I show the flow direction with arrows?

Comment: When you interpolated, you probably created a regular grid of values--tantamount to a DEM. If possible, *that's* what you want to use for input, not the contour lines.  (It is much easier to compute flow directions from a DEM than from a contour line layer.)

Comment: Yes, in output I created a .asc file. How can I extract flow lines direction from a DEM file?

Comment: Is there anything unsatisfactory about [r.flow](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/r.flow.html)?  What about the answer to [this apparent duplicate question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/5651)?  Even more is available by [searching the Web](https://www.google.com/search?q=grass+flow+direction).

Comment: With r.flow I receive a byte allocation problem and the r.fill.dir crashes. I'd be satisfied just with some label on the contour lines. I will try with saga

Comment: Have you seen: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27131/187? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I saw gis.stackexchange.com/a/27131/187 but I didn't understand where all the arrows come from.

Comment: it's a marker line. but is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah, basically that's what I'm looking for. Line marker means that you draw a style and then you loaded it from the propriety window of the layer?